# How to merge audio and video files using ffmpeg in Android?

Tags: android, audio, video, ffmpeg, mp4

I have an existing mp4 file and want to add an audio track to it using `ffmpeg` (the audio track is a wav file recorded from the device's microphone).

I'm executing the following command but it's not generating any output. It seems that fmpeg simply hangs:

```
String[] command = new String[]{"-i", audioFilePath, "-i", videoFilePath, "-codec", "copy", "-shortest", outputFilePath};
```

The logs are:

```
Input #0, wav, from '/data/user/0/android.com.app/cache/30930595321169630261385.audio':
   Duration: 00:00:02.03, bitrate: 705 kb/s
     Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, 1 channels, s16, 705 kb/s
 Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/android.com.app/cache/4632127da0955d4a461dfd622c78233e':
   Metadata:
     major_brand     : isom
     minor_version   : 512
     compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
     encoder         : Lavf57.41.100
   Duration: 00:00:02.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 728 kb/s
     Stream #1:0(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 500x280 [SAR 1:1 DAR 25:14], 724 kb/s, 16.67 fps, 16.67 tbr, 166667 tbn, 33.33 tbc (default)
     Metadata:
       handler_name    : VideoHandler
```

After this, there are no more log statements.

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: FFmpeg does not support muxing PCM in MP4s. You'll have to encode the audio, so replace `"-codec", "copy"` with `"-vcodec", "copy"`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I still get the same behavior with these changes.

Comment: Add `-report` and upload the log.

Comment: Unfortunately I get the following error when trying to set `-report`: Failed to open report "ffmpeg-20170304-142123.log": Read-only file system
Failed to set value '1' for option 'report': Read-only file system
Error parsing global options: Read-only file system

Comment: Looks like that's your primary issue. No write permissions for output folder. You'll still have to change codec to vcodec.

Comment: Indeed it was related to having the correct directory permissions and not necessarily an ffmpeg issues (except for the `vcodec`). Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Use below given Command in FFmpeg Android

```
String[] command  = {"-i", yourVideoPath, "-i", yourAudioPath, "-c:v", "copy", "-c:a", "aac", "-map", "0:v:0", "-map", "1:a:0", "-shortest", file.getAbsolutePath()}
```